# Lost likes on post wordpress

Tags: facebook, wordpress

I have a page in Wordpress, and i lost likes on post Wordpress have a big post whit many likes on Facebook.

And trying to make a better SEO I modify the web address of the entry and lost all the like on facebook. Please, I can’t fix that? Recover all the "Facebook likes", 
I already tried replacing the previous draft and nothing happened, the count is still in 0.  Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a Facebook support question, not a programming one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you almost answered your own question. [Facebook likes are tied to the URL](http://blog.facesharp.com/2010/09/16/facebook-like-button-using-the-like-url-wisely/). Fortunately, Wordpress makes it easy for you to change the permalink of a post.

[image: editing permalinks in Wordpress]

Try to change the permalink to the previous URL, and the likes will magically reappear.

Comment: i thank you ! problem solved ! i miss speling one letter, the last time i do it, and dont get the propied direction, i am so noob ! thank you !